# One select for each another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

In 2 select through each data are loaded:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
$("#Select1").append("<"option value='" + item.Id +"'>"+ item.Id + '' + "<"/option>").text();
$("#Select2").append("<"option value='" + item.Number +"'>"+ item.Number + '' + "<"/option>").text();
});
```

How code it is necessary so Select1 value but text Select2?

Comment: Are you trying to append `<option>` ?

Comment: yes, this code it isn't visible, now change

Comment: you should concatenate the string correctly `"<"option` value is not correct...  try like `'<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.number+'</option>'`

Comment: didn't work '<option value="'+item.id+'">'+item.number+'</option>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script have minor syntax problem so please check below syntax it will helpful to you.

```
<select id="Select1"></select>
<select id="Select2"></select>
<script>
     var aary = [{Id:1,Number:1},{Id:2,Number:2}];
     $.each(aary, function(index, item){
         $("#Select1").append("<option value='" + item.Id +"'>"+ item.Id + '' + "</option>");
         $("#Select2").append("<option value='" + item.Number +"'>"+ item.Number + '' + "</option>");
     });
 </script>
```

Comment: just without quotes it isn't displayed all attributes in select